# Laravel Aggregates query not working according to group by

Tags: laravel

On POS when I place any order it stored the order detail according to the product id on order_details table. I want to sum the quantity order according to product id.
Order Detail table : id, order_id, product_id, total, created_at, updated_at

Product Controller :

```
public function index()
{

 $orderdetail = DB::table('order_details')
             ->select('quantity', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as sum'))
             ->groupBy('product_id')
             ->havingRaw('SUM(quantity)')
             ->get();

    $products = Product::latest()->with('category', 'supplier', 'orderdetail')->get();
    return view('admin.product.index', compact('products', 'orderdetail'));

}
```

On Product Model:

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $dates = [
        'buying_date', 'expire_date',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class);
    }

    public function orderdetail()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\OrderDetail', 'id', 'product_id');
    }
 }

}
```

But it does not show anything on Blade.

on Blade :

```
@foreach($products as $key => $product)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
        <td>
            <img class="img-rounded" style="height:35px; width: 35px;" src="{{ URL::asset("storage/product/".$product->image) }}" alt="{{ $product->name }}">
        </td>
        <td>{{ $product->category->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->supplier->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->code }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->buying_date->toFormattedDateString() }}</td>
        <td>{{ number_format($product->buying_price, 2) }}</td>
        <td>{{ number_format($product->selling_price, 2) }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->product_unit }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->product_unit - $product->sum }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->sum }}</td>
        <td>DLT</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

[This is the result of `dd` on $products and $orderdetail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm4aB.png)

It aggregates the value not showing the blade template. how I show it on the blade or there any problem on model or blade? please help.

Comment: try adding `dd($orderdetail, $products);` before the return statement in your controller to display the data in those variables

Comment: It shows that it's aggregate the value but it does not show on the blade. On Blade I Used this one {{ $product->sum }} on the loop. But not show anything.

Comment: So the problem is in the blade file, not in the controller. Please include in your question a more complete snippet of your loop inside blade

Comment: sorry, now I attached the blade loop on the post. Please kindly see it

Answer (score 1):

Here I solved via this way
on Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $orderdetail = DB::table('order_details')
            ->select('quantity', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as soldunit'))
            ->groupBy('product_id')
            ->get();

    $products = Product::latest()->with('category', 'supplier', 'orderdetail')->get();
    return view('admin.product.index', compact('products', 'orderdetail'));

}
```

and on Model, I have slightly Changed

```
public function orderdetail()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetail','product_id', 'id')->selectRaw('order_details.*,sum(quantity) as soldunit')->groupBy('product_id');
}
```

after this, to access soldunit on the blade I used this one

```
{{ $product->orderdetail->sum('soldunit') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access sum of a column via a defined relationship, you need to add it during your main query:

```
$products = Product::with('category', 'supplier')->with(['orderdetail' => function($query){
   $query->select('id', 'product_id', 'quantity', DB::raw('sum(quantity) as sum'));
}])->get();
```

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work no output is visible. Please kindly help me. I also Highlight now the blade template.

Comment: Did you check dd($products) and also `$product->orderdetail->sum`?

Comment: if i palce dd($product) it wil show "Undefined variable: products". But already i had try this one $product->orderdetail->sum. Nothing shows anything.

Comment: I edited the answer by adding id to select query. Please recheck it. Maybe query needs to know about product_id too. I'll add it too.

Comment: Sadly It will show this Messege Trying to get property 'sum' of non-object (0) after placing new one.

Comment: I think latest is strange in here, so I removed it. If you want to get latest one, you can use `->latest()->first();` instead of `get();` and in this situation, you won't need a foreach in blade side.

Comment: If I place my older one function and place dd($orderdetail, $products); this one shows that both product and order detail sum. From last two days, I will try to solve this but nothing will solve.

Comment: So in your model, remove `latest` and check it again in your blade. If you see something in dd, you can catch it in blade too.

Comment: Many many thanks for helping. Anyhow, I solved it from your ideas and using your updated functions with slightly modify.